# Why are some elements of my Blogger rails app root Article#index not showing up properly on heroku, but work fine locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogger

Everything else is working fine but my models(Articles, Tags, Authors, etc) aren't showing up properly.

What it should look like: [LocalHost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c9Zl.png)

What it looks like on Heroku: [Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVmRl.png)

I ran heroku run rake db:migrate

went through the entire git cycle, etc.

what gives?

Here is my Heroku Log:

```
`2016-01-27T05:04:54.159491+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 05:04:54] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-01-27T05:04:54.159621+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 05:04:54] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2016-01-27T05:04:54.159954+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 05:04:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=22843
2016-01-27T05:04:55.059161+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-01-27T05:04:55.059166+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:22843
2016-01-27T05:04:55.059168+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-01-27T05:04:55.059169+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-01-27T05:04:55.059170+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 104.33.156.67 at 2016-01-27 05:04:55 +0000
2016-01-27T05:04:55.127233+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2016-01-27T05:04:55.195262+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (5.9ms)
2016-01-27T05:04:55.202280+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=f6d476e6-9718-4f42-bc80-77717f0fcee5 fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=146ms status=200 bytes=1556
2016-01-27T05:04:55.191802+00:00 app[web.1]:   Article Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
2016-01-27T05:04:55.197340+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 52.3ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
2016-01-27T05:04:55.563586+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1c3144617da0f508877350fe0ab06ea7c058d62df6f671ddde8529617cf30580.js" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=17a45a37-1f6d-46a9-8c9a-7d8534bfa4ea fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-01-27T05:04:55.563994+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-a681cdeddb3b45d83f9aecea003c058946e8fc0fe08159f100b52f348d537ccd.css" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=0d1ca85f-69a0-464a-8343-1804e4e5292f fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-01-27T05:04:56.013911+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=169764a0-1f9a-433f-bb33-5cb48e81a039 fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-01-27T05:04:54.283840+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-27T05:11:11.742361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=7f940186-4a59-4956-9814-d1051a583f63 fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30ms status=200 bytes=1556
2016-01-27T05:11:11.716258+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 104.33.156.67 at 2016-01-27 05:11:11 +0000
2016-01-27T05:11:11.735097+00:00 app[web.1]:   Article Load (7.7ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
2016-01-27T05:11:11.737544+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 4.6ms | ActiveRecord: 7.7ms)
2016-01-27T05:11:11.722760+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2016-01-27T05:11:11.735817+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.3ms)
2016-01-27T05:11:11.869266+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-a681cdeddb3b45d83f9aecea003c058946e8fc0fe08159f100b52f348d537ccd.css" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=a69d3c72-4195-4a5b-b4e4-10d25a4f42d6 fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=25ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-01-27T05:11:11.857742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1c3144617da0f508877350fe0ab06ea7c058d62df6f671ddde8529617cf30580.js" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=4f0c1675-04ac-4528-a069-b571227466e3 fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-01-27T05:11:12.349478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=a824f3c1-1bfa-4936-a4d4-1d09772b63fa fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=228
2016-01-27T05:11:33.114026+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake run db:migrate` by chrs_espi@yahoo.com
2016-01-27T05:11:36.201452+00:00 heroku[run.2031]: Awaiting client
2016-01-27T05:11:36.240221+00:00 heroku[run.2031]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake run db:migrate`
2016-01-27T05:11:36.671586+00:00 heroku[run.2031]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-27T05:11:40.844250+00:00 heroku[run.2031]: Process exited with status 1
2016-01-27T05:11:59.449972+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by chrs_espi@yahoo.com
2016-01-27T05:12:01.840518+00:00 heroku[run.2233]: Awaiting client
2016-01-27T05:12:01.868168+00:00 heroku[run.2233]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2016-01-27T05:12:02.311946+00:00 heroku[run.2233]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-27T05:12:06.862455+00:00 heroku[run.2233]: State changed from up to complete
2016-01-27T05:12:06.847225+00:00 heroku[run.2233]: Process exited with status 0
2016-01-27T05:11:40.861112+00:00 heroku[run.2031]: State changed from up to complete
2016-01-27T05:12:13.020716+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=9c6ec886-e1a2-4014-9e70-b9a43ef72a6a fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=32ms status=200 bytes=1556
2016-01-27T05:12:13.137652+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-a681cdeddb3b45d83f9aecea003c058946e8fc0fe08159f100b52f348d537ccd.css" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=2de4b506-eaa1-4a23-b034-0bfb40928a2a fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-01-27T05:12:13.147819+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-1c3144617da0f508877350fe0ab06ea7c058d62df6f671ddde8529617cf30580.js" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=97de1be7-c677-4837-be85-58a322f322b2 fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-01-27T05:12:12.993353+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 104.33.156.67 at 2016-01-27 05:12:12 +0000
2016-01-27T05:12:13.015030+00:00 app[web.1]:   Article Load (8.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
2016-01-27T05:12:13.017787+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 2.4ms | ActiveRecord: 8.9ms)
2016-01-27T05:12:12.998667+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
2016-01-27T05:12:13.015467+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.8ms)
2016-01-27T05:12:13.332611+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=salty-gorge-52761.herokuapp.com request_id=521c00fa-6ddc-4e65-a481-c4b63fd13dd5 fwd="104.33.156.67" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=228
2016-01-27T05:45:00.132901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-01-27T05:45:00.132321+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-01-27T05:45:00.141134+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-01-27T05:45:02.249246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 23488 -e production`
2016-01-27T05:45:05.549660+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 05:45:05] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-01-27T05:45:05.549679+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 05:45:05] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2016-01-27T05:45:05.549921+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 05:45:05] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=23488
2016-01-27T05:45:05.979627+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-27T05:45:06.139392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122848+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 05:45:08] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122852+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122854+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122855+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122856+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122857+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122857+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122858+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122861+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122859+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122861+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122860+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122862+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122863+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122864+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-01-27T05:45:08.122967+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 05:45:08] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2016-01-27T05:45:08.123062+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 05:45:08] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-01-27T05:45:08.124002+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-01-27T05:45:09.740154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-01-27T06:19:20.071630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2016-01-27T06:19:20.071630+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2016-01-27T06:19:23.504474+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515937+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 06:19:24] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515942+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515945+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515945+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515946+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515947+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515948+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515948+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515950+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515949+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515951+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515952+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515954+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515953+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.516026+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 06:19:24] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2016-01-27T06:19:24.515954+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2016-01-27T06:19:24.516086+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-01-27 06:19:24] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-01-27T06:19:24.516128+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:23488
2016-01-27T06:19:24.516126+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-01-27T06:19:24.516145+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-01-27T06:19:24.516129+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-01-27T06:19:24.516130+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-01-27T06:19:25.482405+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

`

Comment: Have you seeded your Heroku database?

Comment: No I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Rephrasing question - is there any data in your Heroku database? If the database is empty, obviously there will be no data.

Comment: How do I check my Heroku Database?

Comment: You can check yourself fist - have you added any data to the Heroku database yourself? If not, there is no magic way for it to appear there, so it's probably empty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have heroku CLI installed, run the command: `heroku run rake db:seed`.

Comment: Assuming the data in question is in the seeds.rb file.

Comment: My seeds.rb file is empty, all of the stuff in it is commented out. I tried running rake db:seed but get  ---"rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 10.5.0, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this." I tried running it with bundle exec but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you ran migrations locally, to see these changes in heroku run the command:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: tried it, it runs but the models still don't show up.

Comment: maybe post your log from Heroku

Comment: I added my log from Heroku =)